# How to save Responses of dynamically created Forms by Users

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm relatively new to Ruby on Rails.

I have an app where the **User** can create **Forms**.
I've already declared that user has_many forms and forms belongs_to user.

In addition, Forms have a nested model **Item** which stands for the questions of the Form, allowing a User to make a Form to have multiple questions. Also, Item has_many **Answers** so one question can have multiple answers (like radio or checkbox type of question). Finally, an Answer has_many **Results** allowing to store multiple values later for each answer if it is submited by different people.

Users also have **Children** which I'd like them to apply the **Forms** that they create.

How can I achieve this?
Would you recommend to create an association between my Child model and Form model?

How would you do it?

---

So all I need is to have the `forms` created by one `user` available to be answered for each one of the user's children.

---

> Update:

So I came up with the following idea:

Create a join table between `form` and `children` to map which forms were applied to which child.

Also, the `result` model should have an `answer_id` column of the answer which it responded to. And I guess it will need another column to point the `id` of the join table above to map which form-child belongs to.

¿Do you think this logic is right?

---

When displaying the form to be used, I plan to display `form.title`, loop into their items through each item and display its `item.title` and again loop into its answers through each answer and display its type and label as of the type of field and label for the `form_fields` of each of the results.

The problem now is how can I manage to do this?
I know how to create and save specific number of `Objects` but not Dynamic number of Objects.

> Code:

**form.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, allow_destroy: true
```

**item.rb**

```
belongs_to :form
has_many :answers, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers, allow_destroy: true
```

**answer.rb**

```
belongs_to :item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me point out what may be the problems in your current schema:

> Answer has_many Results allowing to store multiple values later for each answer if it is submited by different people

=> What happens if we want to query how many correct answers in `Form` for a specific `User` or how many correct answers in total for a `Form`?

> Users also have Children which I'd like them to apply the Forms that they create

=> This is kind of confusing, between `User` and `Form` we have the relations: `User` can create many `Forms` and `User` can apply many `Form` via a model `Children`

I have researched on kind of this problem before, here is my suggested schema:

[image]

**Explanation**

- `User` has many `Form` by creating action
- `Form` has many `Item`
- `Item` has many `Question`
- `Question` has many `Answer` (An answer is correct/incorrect)
- `User` applies 1/many `Form`, each time like that, an `AnswerSheet` was created between `User` and `Form`
- `AnswerSheet` contains many `SelectedAnswer` so `SelectedAnswer` belongs to `AnswerSheet` and original `Answer`. Additionally, a `SelectedAnswer` was created by the action that user selects an `Answer`

This is clearer, we can explain the schema with the real meaning, hence, it is easier to understand & implement

**One note** I use `AnswerSheet` instead of your idea of `Children`, I think that makes sense, you can any term you want, but just make sure people understand it :)

Comment: Thank you for answering. Ok first, I should have addressed that questions won't have correct/incorrect answers, however might be a good idea to query for specific answers. Maybe this is what I am looking for, I have to give it a try.

Comment: I am having trouble to implement your solution. The goal now is to be able to create and save dynamic number of `results` depending on how many `items` and `answers` a form could have.

Comment: The schema will work with your expectation, what is your problem, could you describe in detail?

Comment: The problem that I'm having now is that when I make a form for the `result`, it only recognise one field and store it to the database. I want to be able to make only one form for `result` with only one submit button. I will elaborate more in the original post.

Comment: So finally created a model `answered_form` which has both child and form ids, and also has_many `answers` and was able to create a form_for `answered_form` which accepts nested attributes for `answers`. Thanks for helping me redefine the way and achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your Scenario ,I would like to recommend you there is many to many relationship between children and form and also child has_many results.

Comment: Ok, but what exactly this will allow me to do? How can I use the Form created by the User and then apply it to their Children? Somehow, I need to display a specific Form created by the User for a Child, and then be able to store in the database the values of each "Result".